# Java ? super T in Collections copy why correct work

Tags: java

```
    List<String> srcList = new ArrayList<>();
    srcList.add("a");
    srcList.add("b");
    srcList.add("c");

    List<String> descList = new ArrayList<>(3);
    descList.add("1");
    descList.add("2");
    descList.add("3");
    // public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src)
    Collections.copy(descList, srcList);

    for (String item: descList) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }

    List<? super String> listC = new ArrayList<>();
    listC.add("A");
    listC.add("B");
    listC.add("C");

    Collections.copy(listC, srcList);

    for (String item : listC) { System.out.println(item); }// complie error.
```

`<? super T>` means T or T's super class.
In method `Collections.copy()` param `dest` can correct work on `foreach`.
Why custom List Object `listC` can't work on get item of this list.

Comment: Because the `item` in your loop is not necessarily a string. It could also be an instance of one of `String`'s superclasses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By declaring `List<? super String> listC`, you're saying that `listC` could be a `List<String>`, or a `List<Object>` or a `List<CharSequence>`, or a `List` of any other supertype of `String`.

Now, the line `for (String item: listC)` makes no sense, because if `listC` is a `List<Object>`, or something else other than `List<String>`, then its contents may not necessarily be `String`s.  This is what the compiler is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

This seems obvious that you have copied all elements from `srcList` to `listC`, so now the resultant list is of type `List<? super String>`.

when you're saying `for (String item : listC)` compiler will try to convert the type `? super String` to `String` type. This is not allowed. Hence the compiler error. You should use the same type for both lists. As mentioned by @DawoodibnKareem, `List<? super String>` could be `List<Object>`, `List<CharSequence>` or a List of any other supertype of `String`. List of different types is not compatible.